# Does there exist such $100$-element set $A$, so that for any $x$ in $A$ there is a number $2x^2-1$ in $A$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried the obvious example:
$\{\cos x, \cos 2x, \cos 4x, \ldots, \cos2^{99}x\}$ for some angle $x$. But the example in the answers in my book says there has to be a particular $x$ value, for example, $x=\frac{2\pi}{2^{100}+1}$. Can you explain me why isn't it true for any x and what's so special about $\frac{2\pi}{2^{100}+1}$?

Comment: The question is asked in a barely understandable way.

Comment: Say $x=1$.  Then $\cos \left(2^{99}\right)$ is in your list but $\cos\left (2^{100}\right)=2\cos^2 \left(2^{99}\right)-1$ is not.

Comment: Note that $\cos4\pi=\cos2\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special thing about this number is

$$2^{100}\frac{2\pi}{2^{100}+1}=2\pi-\frac{2\pi}{2^{100}+1}$$ and the cosines are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $2\cos^2(x)-1=\cos(2x)$, and that $2\cos^2(2x)-1=\cos(4x)$, etc, but there must exist an element in $A$ that is equal to $2\cos^2((2^{99})x)-1=\cos(2^{100}x)$.

The simplest way to do this is make $\cos(x)=\cos(2^{100}x)$.

That would mean $x(2^{100}-1)$ is a multiple of $2\pi$.

Can you proceed?